# Llamada al backend con serverSideProps sale mal (Nextjs 13)

Tags: nextjs

Estoy haciendo un catálogo donde necesito que al clickear en un producto, se redirija a la página de dicho producto con toda la información. Para esto estoy usando rutas dinámicas e intento usar serverSideProps para obtener los datos del producto seleccionado, pero por algun motivo la llamada sale mal.
esto es lo que me sale en la terminal:
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 88 ms (341 modules)
error - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8000

y la función es la siguiente

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
    // const url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL + `/administracion/producto/${query.producto}`
    // const res = await fetch(url)
   const res = await axios
    .get(
        `/administracion/producto/${query.producto}`, // Usa axios.get en lugar de fetch
    )
    .then(res => res.data)
    // const producto = await res.json();
    console.log(res)
    return {
        props: {

        },
    };

}
```

el script se llama [producto].js, por eso en la url pongo '${query.producto}', para obtener el id del producto. Si escribo en el http://localhost:8000/administracion/producto/1 (1 en este caso es un id de un producto) me devuelve en pantalla los datos del producto con id 1, pero con la función de serverSideProps no está pasando

Comment: Si estás usando el nuevo app router deberás traer tus datos de esta manera: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating